# Error 500 when including controller file in Route

Tags: 8, routes

I am trying to upgrade a mailing list from drupal 7 to 8. I am getting an 500 error when I include my controller in the route file. I checked the path in both route and controllers and almost tried removing all values from the class, still I am getting the error my route file is:

```
mailing_list.admin:
  path: '/admin/structure/mailing_list'
  defaults:
_controller:'\Drupal\mailing_list\Controller\MailingListController::mailingListList'
_title: 'Mailing List'
  requirements:
_permissions: 'administer mailing lists'
```

My Controller Code is:

```
namespace Drupal\mailing_list\Controller;
class MailingListController extends ControllerBase {
  public function mailingListList() {
$output = array('table', array('header' => '1'));
}
}
```

I have removed the lines in controller function to avoid 500 error, but still I am getting 500 error.

Comment: Have you looked at your apache error log to see the cause of this error?

Comment: it's so hard to find your problem. you need following [topic](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/show-all-errors-while-developing) to show error. May be need add `$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose';` to file setting.php. In your case, may be wrong indent file routing or missing statement `use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;`

Comment: Without knowing the error it's just guesswork which doesn't suit Q+A. Please check your logs, do a bit of debugging, and update the question when you've got some more information. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is the entirety of your controller, then you are missing `use` statement for `ControllerBase`.

```
namespace Drupal\mailing_list\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class MailingListController extends ControllerBase {
  public function mailingListList() {
    $output = array('table', array('header' => '1'));
  }
}
```

You also need to return a `Response` or renderable array from the controller method the route calls.

Example:

```
namespace Drupal\mailing_list\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class MailingListController extends ControllerBase {
  public function mailingListList() {
    $output = [];
    $output['#markup'] = $this->t('Hello!');
    return $output;
  }
}
```

See: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/introductory-drupal-8-routes-and-controllers-example

If that does not work you need to post the full error you are getting.